# Did György Sherfezi fall from the 10th floor on a passing Laszlo Karvasha and both survived?

Tags: medical-science, history, physiology

Some researchers of **Coincidence** insist on the veracity of the story:

> "A resident of Budapest György Sherfezi fell out of the 10th floor
>   window and landed on a passing Laszlo Karvasha. Exactly one year later
>   the exact same case was repeated with the same characters, and both
>   survived".

http://psychoformer.blogspot.ru/2012/10/almanac-matches-in-1992-french-artist.html

Comment: What is a "Laszlo Karvasha"?  I Googled it and the only results were from this StackExchange, and the link you posted.

Comment: Sounds like http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36104/did-joseph-figlock-catch-the-same-baby-falling-from-the-same-window-twice?newsletter=1&nlcode=684865%7ce628 Maybe just an extension of the same event?

Comment: user1008646  Laszlo Karvasha is a Hungarian person's name))

Comment: BlueMoon93 The story about Figlock appeared to be true. So ii is really curious, if a hungarian case is true.